# Observe changes of instance variable in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a `property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *currentContent`, I also have a `property(strong, nonatomic)NSMutableArray *cellHeights` to keep track of the cell heights cos the user could expand or collapse each cell. The `self.currentContent` is set by another controller which load data from a web service, so it will change as the data load, I want to keep both of these variables in sync. As soon as `currentContent` is updated, I want to update `cellHeights`. How do I do that?

I tried:

```
- (void)setCurrentContent:(NSMutableArray *)currentContent{
    _currentContent = currentContent;
    self.cellHeights = [NSMutableArray arrayWithDefaultHeightsForCellCount:[currentContent count]];
}
```

But it's not working, cos it will only be set at the first time when I set `currentContent`, when it's empty. So `self.cellHeights` currently will stay empty. When there is finally value in `self.currentContent`, `self.cellHeights` was not updated.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar thing before, with variable cell heights depending on the content from your web-service, and I'd advise that keeping an array of cell heights might not be the best idea.

What I did was to create a 'fake' cell in the viewDidLoad: method, that I use just to calculate cell heights.

Then I use the 'heightForRowAtIndexPath' method to specify how tall cell should be by populating the 'fake' cell with the data for the index path, then finding out how tall that cell is.  For example:

```
@interface MyTableViewController()

@property (nonatomic, strong ) MyCustomTableViewCell *cellForTestingHeight;

@end




@implementation MyTableViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad]

   self.cellForTestingHeight = [[MyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSDictionary *myData = [self.data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.cellForTestingHeight.viewData = myData;

    return self.cellForTestingHeight.height;
}

@end
```

This code assumes that you've created a class called MyCustomTableViewCell which has a method to set the viewData property on it, and that after setting that property you'll be able to tell how tall that cell will be by accessing a height property.

Comment: Thanks for this nice pattern, I'll definitely use it in the future. But currently I want to be able to expand and collapse the cells, thus I need to keep track of all the heights in an array. How do I know if the current cell is need to be expanded or not from the test cell? Maybe I need to put a flag onto `myData`? But that's kinda injecting onto the model layer. I'm not sure my clarification makes sense. But thanks...

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is observe changes to the mutable array itself, not your property which references the array. This should be straightforward but unfortunately there is a twist...

OK, let's assume there is no twist and rather than an `NSMutableArray` your property is of type `MyObservableClass`. Then to setup the observing you would do something like this (all code is pseudo - i.e. typed into the answer):

```
- (void)setCurrentContent:(MyObservableClass *)currentContent
{
   if(_currentContent)
      [_currentContent removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myObservableProperty"];

   _currentContent = currentContent;
   [_currentContent addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"myObservableProperty" ...];
}
```

Now whenever the `currentContent` is changed your code stops observing the properties of its old value and starts observing properties of its new value.

Easy, but its not quite that simple for arrays...

The twist, though KVO will inform an observer of additions, deletions and changes to a collection the `NSMutableArray` class doesn't issue those notifications. You need to use a proxy for the array, and such a proxy is provided by the frameworks - see for example `NSArrayController` and `mutableArrayValueForKey:`. However the second part of the twist is that the changes to the array must be done through this proxy - you can't have your client call `setCurrentContent` and pass any `NSMutableArray` if you are going to observe it, your client needs to pass in the proxy... Whether you can use this easily in your design you'll have to figure out. You'll need to read [Automatic Change Notification in this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOCompliance.html) and other Apple docs to sort this out.

This sounds more complicated that it needs to be, maybe somebody else will provide a more succinct way of doing this.

Comment: The alternative is to make all changes to the array through the methods listed under ["Indexed to-many relationship compliance"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/Compliant.html)

Comment: Appreciate the answer. If the `NSMutableArray` is hard to observe, maybe I have to observe the class that is assigning the `currentContent` to my current `TaskTableViewDelegate` class. In this case, it's `TaskListViewController`, which has a `currentTask` property, maybe I should also create a protocol so I could use this current delegate class with other controllers?